# Make a tag in a command from given arguments

Tags: tags

I am trying to make a LaTeX document for maths notes.

I have written the following commands:

```
\newcommand{\definition}[2]{\textbf{Definition} (#1): #2 \index{#1} \tag{definition_#1}}
\newcommand{\definitionref}[1]{\nameref{#1}}
```

I would like, whenever the `\definition` command is used, a tag to be created based on what the defined object is called. For example, `\definition{Vector}{blah}` should be tagged with `definition_Vector`.

This does not compile, though. Any suggestions for how I can get this to work?

Comment: Where do you get `\tag` from? Do you mean `\label{ }` or `\index{ }`?

Comment: please show a small complete example and the error you got. `_` and `\tag` are math mode constructs, but your fragment appears entirely text mode and I can not guess how you intend `\definition` to be used

Comment: This sounds like something you probably want to use theorem environments for, e.g. `amsthm` or `ntheorem`.